# Enbedded fonts in Flash CS6 that renders like device fonts

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

Device fonts look really good and I've always had issues with how the embedded fonts look in Flash. I havent used Flash for a while, so my question is:

Is there any way I can have fonts render like device fonts (cleartype?) but still get the safety that they will work on all computers even if the font is not installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was satisfied from "Flash Text Engine" (FTE) with my embedded fonts.....

Renders the same on all machines and look great...! (Tested on Windows and Linux)

cons:
You need to develop your own TextField or get from Open Source....
including InputField!!

If you need any help, I have a class like this but it need modificaton to your needs!

Good Luck!!